# Let $F:\mathscr{A}\to\mathscr{B}$ be an equivalence of Abelian categories. Must $F$ be additive?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

What if we simply require $\mathscr{A}$ to be pre-additive, or additive? I have seen it stated without proof that if $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are abelian categories, then any equivalence $F:\mathscr{A}\to\mathscr{B}$ must be additive, but I have not been able to prove that. This is my work so far:

Clearly, $F(x\xrightarrow{0}y)=F(x)\xrightarrow{0}F(y)$ by factoring the first morphism through the zero object. However, the fact that $F$ is fully faithful does not seem to be sufficient to prove that $F$ induces homomorphism of Hom-sets (at least not by naïve algebraic manipulations). Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: An equivalence of categories preserves identity morphisms, finite products and finite coproducts.  In an Abelian category, the finite product equals the finite coproduct.  Thus every equivalence between two Abelian categories also preserves the diagonal and codiagonal.  For $f,g\in [a,a']$, $f+g$ equals the composition of the diagonal $a \to a\times a$, the product morphism $f\times g:a\times a \to a'\times a'$, and the codiagona $a'\times a'\to a'$.  Thus an equivalence of Abelian categories induces group homomorphisms of Hom sets.

Comment: @JasonStarr that's an answer, why don't you post it as one?

Comment: underlying Jason's answer is the following fact: say C is a category, then being additive (or abelian) is a property of C, not extra structure we add on top if. (i.e. Hom being an abelian group is more or less a consequence of coproducts being isomorphic to products). I learned this fact from Jacob Lurie's thesis, when he discusses stable categories (but this fact is surely way older than that).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am posting the comment above as an answer.

An equivalence of categories preserves identity morphisms, finite product, and finite coproducts.  Thus, it also preserves diagonal morphisms and codiagonal morphisms.  In an Abelian category, the finite product equals the finite coproduct.  For every $f,g\in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(a,a')$, the morphism $f+g$ equals the composition of the diagonal morphism, $\Delta_a: a\to a\times a$, the product morphism $f\times g : a\times a \to a'\times a'$, and the codiagonal morphism $a'\times a' \to a'$.  Thus an equivalence of Abelian categories induces group homomorphism of Hom sets.

Comment: This also works for functors between linear categories (aka preadditive categories) which preserve finite (co)products.